# Modal fade-in animation ends with jump to top layer

Tags: next.js, css-animations, fadein

My keyframe animation for a modal which is supposed to fade in when opened is at the top level of the z-index, after adding the animation it fades in, but appears stacked behind  a couple other components which are explicitly stacked at lower indices and just when it ends the modal "jumps" to the front into its proper index.

[image: Sliding image carousel in the background that overlaps the modal]

[image: After animation ends, modal jumped to front]

```
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease forwards; 
  
  .modalContent {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .55);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1010;

    h2 {
      margin: 0.5em;
    }

    .modalContent button {
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```
import styles from "./modal.module.scss"
import Contact from "../contact/contact"
import React from "react"

function Modal ({ isOpen, onClose }) {

    if(!isOpen) {
        return null
    }

    const handleOverlayClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        if(e.target === e.currentTarget) {
            onClose()
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.modal}>
            <div className={styles.modalOverlay} onClick={handleOverlayClick}>
                <div className={styles.modalContent}>
                    <h2>Say hi and leave me a message!</h2>
                    <Contact/>
                    <button onClick={onClose}>X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

I thought the fade-in animation may be affected by the blur and removed it or separating it into another div, but it seems to be the issue of the entire animation, because without the animation the modal just pops into visibility in the correct z-index without issue.

I am hoping to resolve this and keeping the fade-in effect, as this project was meant to improve my design skills and I apply various other transitions to components for practise

Comment: After investigating further there are 2 key issues here
1. due to my modalOverlay having the position: fixed, the modal z-index is getting ignored - that is until the animation has finished; then the modal jumps to the top
2. the property backdrop-filter: blur() is still very unpredictable and unreliable